# Is there a way to simulate filling a form with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, autohotkey

I'm trying to write a AutoHotkey script which should automatically login to a webpage with Google Chrome. (No focus on security here).

Currently I'm using [Chrome.ahk](https://github.com/G33kDude/Chrome.ahk) with JavaScript's `.focus()` method + AHK's `Send` command.

I would prefer letting the script directly change the input values of the login form so that it can work in the background. So for example like

```
document.getElementById('username').value = 'testusr';
```

The problem is that the webpages I want to use this script on do not recognize that their inputs have changed with this JavaScript method (I also tried JS' `setAttribute` and `setAttributeValue` from Chrome DevTools).

I think this is due to some kind of form-control which these webpages are using and DirtyFlags which are not being set to true when programmatically changing the values. But I can't confirm that since I'm not the webmaster of any of these pages.

So my question is if there is a way to simulate the keypresses with JS or Chrome DevTools or maybe a different solution which would set the dirty flag to true.

Comment: Look into automation web drivers like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) that can be imported into a project in just about any language that makes it so your actions are mimicked more human like using the actual automation API spec being built into browsers, the [WebDriver API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/).

Comment: I think the web page must be `visible` for a script to act on it (whether keyboard/mouse/microphone or directly changing input values), so can't be done in the background. Activate the browser in a small window and minimize again as quick as possible is best you'll do. Can I make that an answer?